Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application. Jar file
I have compiled my JavaFx into a single jar file with all dependencies, but an error occurs. How can I solve this problem? I use Gradle for dependency management.
Java 17.0.1

Gradle code:
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["resources/"]

group = 'org.yoba'
version = '1.0'
mainClassName = "launcher.Launcher"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "21.0.2"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.web']
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'launcher.Launcher'
    }
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:21.0.2'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-web:21.0.2'
}

Couldn't find anything that fit

openjfx.io -> getting started: runtime images.

This I understand, can I somehow pack the SDK inside the jar file to run it without specifying the path to the library?

What does your launcher.Launcher class look like?

"can I somehow pack the SDK inside the jar file to run it without specifying the path to the library?" -> You can link the runtime with your required modules to create a runtime image and then distribute that as a zip with an execution shell script, or package it into an installer using jpackage. Or you can shade everything into a jar file using the jar artifacts from maven central that include native components as documented at the link I provided, though that isn't really a supported configuration. What you decide to do is up to you.

I thought I could add the java fx SDK to the project files and add it to the gradle script. Then pack everything into one file.

The recommended way to deploy a JavaFX application is as a self-contained package (e.g., jlink / jpackage, GraalVM native image, etc.). Deploying a fat executable jar file is an unsupported configuration, though it is still possible to do. The error you're getting indicates your main class is a subclass of Application, which leads to said error if and when the javafx.graphics module is not in the boot module layer (i.e., when JavaFX is on the class-path instead of the module-path). That is why I asked what your launcher.Launcher class looks like.

This GitHub repo contains a Gradle JavaFX app including a working fat jar task: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppGradleNonModular. All JFX dependencies will be wrapped in the created fat jar so you can just double click and start it.

"I thought I could add the java fx SDK to the project files and add it to the gradle script. Then pack everything into one file."
This is possible.
This GitHub repo contains a Gradle JavaFX app including a working fat jar task:
www.github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

All JFX dependencies will be included in the created fat jar so you can just double click and start it.
Note:
This is a non-modular approach.
Note 2:
You can easily wrap this fat JAR afterwards in a native executable with e. g. JPackage if you want to.
